# Spacing after figure without caption

Tags: spacing, floats

I am using images to provide visual support to a user-guide. I "hide" captions since they are not really relevant in this situation but that leaves a big space after each figures.

I tried reducing the space with commands such as `\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}` but that reduce top spacing as well which means my figures are too close up to the text, and I still have a big space at the bottom.

The current fix I use is forcing a negative `vspace` after each figures, which does not seem quite appropriate.

#### MWE

Test package

```
\ProvidesPackage{test}
% Floats
\floatplacement{figure}{H} % Forces default figure position to here
% Resize small figures not to stretch
\def\autoscale{
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width<\linewidth
    \Gin@nat@width
  \else
    \linewidth
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\includeimage}[1]{
  \IfFileExists{#1}{\includegraphics[width=\autoscale]{#1}}{\break}
}
```

Document

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, titlepage, draft]{article} % A4 = 210x297mm
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[
  margin          = 2cm,
  top             = 75pt,
  bottom          = 75pt,
  headheight      = 28.5pt,
  headsep         = 12pt,
  footskip        = 36pt,
  heightrounded,
  marginparwidth  = 0pt,
  marginparsep    = 0pt,
  verbose,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{test}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includeimage{img/1.png}
  % \caption{no caption}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includeimage{img/2.png}
  % \caption{no caption}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The images are ~1350px by ~700px.

#### Screenshots

Here are some screenshots describing the issue:

1. Current situation

[image: Current situation]

2. Expected output

[image: Expected output]

Grey shapes are text, white ones are figures. I would like to have both of them fitting in the same page by reducing the bottom padding after the first one.

I am open to using any useful package to do so.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I added a MWE that should reproduce the issue as described.

Comment: Thank you for adding a MWE, but: 1) what is `test` package? 2) do you intend `\includegraphics` instead of `\includeimage`? 3) put `example-image-a` (or similar) from `graphicx` package instead of your own images, because we don't have them.

Comment: Did you try adding the`\raggedbottom` directive in your preamble? B.t.w., what's the point of adding  a `\label`  if you can't cross-reference the figure?

Comment: @CarLaTeX My bad, forgot to add the package to my MWE. It is a simple rework of the includegraphics function to automatically format figures properly (for the purpose of my document).

Comment: You do not use a caption, and from the code for package `test` I deduce that you do not want your images to be placed by the LaTeX algorithm either, but to occur were you put them (hence placement specification `H`). My question would then be, why bother with the `figure` environment at all. Instead, just call `\includegraphics{}` (without `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` directly in the text. That will place your image where you put it (i.e. not floating) and should IMHO also get rid of any additional spacing around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about not using the `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}
\section{With \texttt{figure} environment}
\lipsum[4]

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\clearpage
\section{Without \texttt{figure} environment}
\lipsum[4]

\includegraphics{example-image-a}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

However, in this true minimal working example you will see, that the space around `figure` is not extraordinarily large, and not larger below the figure than above, when there is no caption. I personally find the space introduced by `figure` quite appropriate, more so than with a simple `\includegraphics{}` (no space at all). This suggests that something else in your code messes around with those spaces, if you get such weird results.

Comment: You are right. I guess I was used to wrapping images in a figure environment so I did not think about just including the picture.
Thank you very much for your help.